# How to convert textInput to output in the Shiny appplication with insertUIs

Tags: r, shiny, textinput

I have a small Shiny app to randomize speaker's list using insertUI (in case there is be more of them).

The problem is that I only got it working using **textInput** and I fail to get it done without the input box - just to display the text without the box.
It's more of an aesthetics thing but after many hours of unsuccessful trials I'm reaching out for help here.

I really appreciate your help.
Herunia

Here is the code:

```
if (interactive()) {
       
  ui <- fluidPage(      
    actionButton("add", "Next speaker")
         )
  
  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    a <- sample(c("Speaker 1","Speaker 2","Speaker 3","Speaker 4","Speaker 5"))
    uiCount = reactiveVal(0)
    observeEvent(input$add, {
      
      uiCount(uiCount()+1)
      insertUI(
        selector = "#add",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add), paste0("Speaker #", uiCount() , ": "),
                       placeholder = a[uiCount()] ), 
      )
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `?textOutput`?

Comment: I tried but I was unable to get it working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this closer to what you want?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Next speaker"),
  uiOutput("txt")
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  a <- sample(c("Speaker 1","Speaker 2","Speaker 3","Speaker 4","Speaker 5"))
  uiCount = reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    uiCount(uiCount()+1)
    
    output$txt <- renderUI({
      div(
        p(
          paste0("Speaker #", uiCount(), " :", a[uiCount()])
        ) #close p
      ) #close div
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, this is awesome - many thanks for your help!